# How can I store a regex pattern in a MySQL field and check an input against it?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, mariadb, percona

My application is made up of several microservices and I am now working on the API Gateway and Authorization Microservice. Each incoming request will be validated and authorized depending on the user's permissions to perform this activity. An activity is made up of a verb (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) and an ENDPOINT (/interpretations/q44nAj91aH6nd/)

I have a MySQL table listing all activities and want to match the user's request's endpoint to the matching activity (row) in the table.

```
    CREATE TABLE `activities` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `method` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'GET',
      `url_regex` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `activities` (`id`, `url`, `method`, `url_regex`)
    VALUES
        (1,'/interpretations/','POST',''),
        (2,'','GET','/interpretations/[a-Z0-9]+/');
```

My question is, how can I match the row 2 for this given request's endpoint: `/interpretations/q44nAj91aH6nd/` (which should match the regex pattern `/interpretations/[a-Z0-9]+/`).

When I try the below, it does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM `activities` WHERE `url_regex` RLIKE "/interpretations/q44nAj91aH6nd/";

# also tried inverting

SELECT * FROM `activities` WHERE "/interpretations/q44nAj91aH6nd/" RLIKE `url_regex`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQl, the regex pattern comes AFTER the RLIKE and the input data comes before, hence:

```
SELECT * FROM `activities` WHERE "/interpretations/q44nAj91aH6nd/" RLIKE `url_regex`;
```

PS, your regexp has a syntax error in the character range. Try this instead:

```
/interpretations/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/
```

To test your regexes first, pass the input and the pattern as straight strings:

```
SELECT * FROM `activities` WHERE  '/interpretations/q44nAj91aH6nd/' RLIKE  '/interpretations/[a-Z0-9]+/';
```

Gives "invalid character range". You don't see this in a query, because the pattern error doesn't halt the query, it just drops the row

Some testing/demo available at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82e917/2

Comment: Yes; amended post to give info on this

Comment: Your example is wrong(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82e917/2). In first row insert you are not taking any value for the column "url_regex". But for seconds row you are taking.

Comment: Not my data in that fiddle; it's the OP's data (if you look at the question). The OP's question was "why does row 2 not match" and the answer was "because there is an error in your regex syntax". No-one was asking about row 1 at all, but you're right in your observation that it doesn't have any data - it's just that the observation isn't really relevant to anything/isn't correct to say that the example is  "wrong"

Answer (score 0):

`RLIKE` cares about the order of the arguments.  Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM `activities`
WHERE '/interpretations/q44nAj91aH6nd/' RLIKE url_regex;
```

Change the regular expression to:

```
INSERT INTO `activities` (`id`, `url`, `method`, `url_regex`)
    VALUES (1, '/interpretations/', 'POST', ''),
           (2, '', 'GET', '/interpretations/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/');
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afe26/1) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: just edited the question - it still doesn't work. is the pattern wrong then?